# WEB API controller class is not being called from Blazor http client

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages

I am trying to call the list of employees from my blazor application using api. When I try to call the method from API from my service controller class , immediately it would be going to  razor html without going to api controller. This is my code

My  blazor project startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddHttpClient<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44300/");
        });
    }
```

EmployeeListBase.cs

```
 public class EmployeeListBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IEmployeeService EmployeeService { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Employees = (await EmployeeService.GetEmployees()).ToList();
    }


}
```

Employee service class

```
 public async  Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployees()
    {
        
      
        return await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<Employee[]>("api/employees");
    }
```

But when I call httpClient.GetJsonAsync api , it will immediately going to EmployeeListBase razor html file without going API controller. API address is working fine . I copied and paste the http api address in postman , it is working perfect. But when I call through blazor app it is not going to api controller . When I debug Employees , the data would be null. Any help would be very appreciated

```html
@page "/"
@inherits EmployeeListBase

<h3>Employee List</h3>

<div class="card-deck">
    @foreach (var employee in Employees)
    {
        <div class="card m-3" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width:30.5%;">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3>@employee.FirstName @employee.LastName</h3>
            </div>
            <img class="card-img-top imageThumbnail" src="@employee.PhotoPath" />
            <div class="card-footer text-center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary m-1">View</a>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary m-1">Edit</a>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger m-1">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Check the network log in the browser. Enable CORS if you need it on server side.

Comment: `call the method from API from my service controller class , immediately it would be going to razor html without going to api controller` I did a test based on the code you shared, which work well on my side. To troubleshot the issue, you can check if any exception in browser console tab and you can use fiddler to capture request and check if something wrong with that request.

Comment: Besides, you can debug your code and check logs about the request that you made from `EmployeeService` in visual studio Output window.